Oracle SQL Grouping same value records in particular order
I have simple table of Time and Task columns where it is ordered by Time and has associated task to it as per below example.
Question: How to group the tasks and get the earliest time of every time the task is changing?
SELECT 
    "Time",
    "Task"
FROM my_query
ORDER BY
    "Time"




Time
Task




06:06:41
Repack


06:06:44
Vehicle Load


06:06:45
Vehicle Load


06:06:46
Vehicle Load


06:10:47
Repack


06:10:48
Vehicle Load


06:10:51
Vehicle Load


06:10:52
Vehicle Load


06:15:45
Repack


06:16:13
Repack


06:24:30
Repack


06:24:34
Vehicle Load


06:26:11
Repack


06:26:12
Vehicle Load


06:26:13
Vehicle Load


06:29:33
Relocate


06:46:07
Repack


06:46:45
Repack


07:01:54
Pick


07:04:12
Pick


07:04:26
Marshal


07:06:28
Pick


07:17:06
Repack


07:17:10
Vehicle Load


07:17:11
Vehicle Load


07:21:55
Repack



The output is required:



Time
Task




06:06:41
Repack


06:06:44
Vehicle Load


06:10:47
Repack


06:10:48
Vehicle Load


06:15:45
Repack



and so on...
I have tried DENSE_RANK(), ROW_NUMBER() functions without any luck.. Please help

You can use the LAG analytic function to get the previous Task and then find when that changes:
SELECT Time,
       Task
FROM   (
  SELECT Time,
         Task,
         LAG(task) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS prev_task
  FROM my_query
)
WHERE  task != prev_task
OR     prev_task IS NULL

Or, from Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGINZE to do row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT time, Task
FROM   my_query
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         ORDER BY time
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN (not_same)
         DEFINE not_same AS task != PREV(task) OR PREV(task) IS NULL
       )

Or, if you did want to use ROW_NUMBER then you can use:
SELECT time,
       Task
FROM   (
  SELECT time,
         Task,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY task, grp ORDER BY time) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT Time,
           Task,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time)
             - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY task ORDER BY time) AS grp
    FROM   my_query
  )
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY time

(But the first two are probably going to be more efficient.)
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE my_query (Time, Task) AS
SELECT INTERVAL '06:06:41' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:06:44' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:06:45' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:06:46' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:10:47' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:10:48' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:10:51' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:10:52' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:15:45' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:16:13' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:24:30' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:24:34' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:26:11' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:26:12' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:26:13' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:29:33' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Relocate'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:46:07' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '06:46:45' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '07:01:54' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Pick'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '07:04:12' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Pick'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '07:04:26' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Marshal'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '07:06:28' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Pick'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '07:17:06' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '07:17:10' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '07:17:11' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Vehicle Load' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT INTERVAL '07:21:55' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Repack'       FROM DUAL;

All output:



TIME
TASK




+00 06:06:41.000000
Repack


+00 06:06:44.000000
Vehicle Load


+00 06:10:47.000000
Repack


+00 06:10:48.000000
Vehicle Load


+00 06:15:45.000000
Repack


+00 06:24:34.000000
Vehicle Load


+00 06:26:11.000000
Repack


+00 06:26:12.000000
Vehicle Load


+00 06:29:33.000000
Relocate


+00 06:46:07.000000
Repack


+00 07:01:54.000000
Pick


+00 07:04:26.000000
Marshal


+00 07:06:28.000000
Pick


+00 07:17:06.000000
Repack


+00 07:17:10.000000
Vehicle Load


+00 07:21:55.000000
Repack



fiddle

The following should do the trick (in any DBMS):
WITH ranked_tasks AS (
  SELECT 
    "Time",
    "Task",
    LAG("Task") OVER (ORDER BY "Time") AS prev_task
  FROM my_query
)
SELECT 
  "Time",
  "Task"
FROM ranked_tasks
WHERE "Task" != prev_task OR prev_task IS NULL
ORDER BY "Time"

